# Barcode scanner on Zebra device stops working after camera usage

Tags: maui, barcode-scanner, datawedge

On our mobile .NET MAUI app, we use two modes of scanning - with device camera (using BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui package), or with hardware barcode scanner on Zebra devices (using the Zebra DataWedge solution). Some devices have both camera and a scanner (Zebra TC-20 and TC-26 for example). However when on this device I open the camera and scan a barcode, the barcode scanner no longer triggers.

Restarting the app does seem to solve this, until I open any page that has the BarcodeScanner.Mobile on it. Then it doesn't trigger again. To get it working again, I need to reinstall app, or delete all local app files.

DataWedge profile I create for this app seems unchanged. When I delete it and app creates it again, issue persists.

Has anyone dealt with this issue, or has any suggestions on what should I look?